# elisp mode set tab width to 2 spaces

Tags: indentation

My global `tab-width` is set to 4. But in elisp-mode I get 6 spaces per tab in indentation. So the code after auto indenting looks like this:

```
(defun new-eshell ()
      (interactive)
      (when (one-window-on-screen-p)
            (let* ((lines (window-body-height))
                        (new-window (split-window-vertically (floor (* 0.7 lines)))))
                  (select-window new-window)
                  (buffer-name (eshell "eshell"))
                  )))
```

How can I set the indentation to 2 spaces?

**Update: info for NickD**

After I type `C-h m` I get this:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Cl-Old-Struct-Compat Delete-Selection Diff-Auto-Refine Display-Time
Eldoc Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Eldoc
Global-Font-Lock Global-Undo-Tree Ivy Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel
Override-Global Pyvenv Shell-Dirtrack Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree
Yas Yas-Global

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Emacs-Lisp mode defined in ‘elisp-mode.el’:
Major mode for editing Lisp code to run in Emacs.
```

Doing the same in `emacs -Q` gives 2 spaces. So, something is wrong with the configs.

Comment: What does `C-h v lisp-body-indent RET` say?

Comment: @NickD lisp-body-indent is a variable defined in ‘lisp-mode.el’. Its value is 2

Comment: What exactly are you typing in? Are you typing `TAB`s or are you letting the mode decide the indentation?

Comment: @NickD I am typing <Tab>.

Comment: So why not type anything and let the mode decide the indentation? If you press RET at the end of the first line, does it not indent 2 spaces automatically on the next line?

Comment: @NickD It decides, but the indentation is too big: 6 spaces instead of 2.

Comment: Let me try again: what is the major mode of your buffer? `C-h m` should tell you that. Now type `(defun new-eshell ()` followed by RET (or Enter). Now type `(interactive)` - do NOT type any TABs. Is the `(interactive)` indented 2 spaces or 6? Now do the same thing  but starting with `emacs -Q` - what do you observe?

Comment: @NickD Did what you told. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was here: `(setq lisp-indent-offset 6)`. Changed it to `(setq lisp-indent-offset 2)` and it started to work.